# LINQ to SQL column has keyword as column name, how to quote/escape

Tags: c#, linq, syntax, escaping

In a LINQ to SQL statement I've got a column name in the database that's also a C# keyword (void).  How do I get the compiler to treat this as an object property and not the keyword?

I could re-write this in with the method notation, sure, but there's got to be a way to give the compiler a hint here...

```
var p = from c in mytable
        where c.id = rowNumber
        select ( new { voidedState = c.void } );  // <--- Problem is here
```

The error is:

```
Identifier expected; 'void' is a keyword
```

I can't argue with that, I'm just looking for a workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Precede the identifier with a "@":

```
@void
```

Is the name of an identifier "void", not the keyword (this works anywhere an identifier is needed).

Comment: I've been looking all over for this.  Thanks.